# Creating a column loop within a table loop to calculate fill rate for all fields in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, fill, rate

I have 2 databases with over 400 tables for which I have to calculate fill rates. I have a loop for calculating fill rates for all columns in a table, but how can I do it for all tables in a database?? Please help!
I am using SQL Server.

Here is the code for looping through all columns in a table for calculating fill rate-

```
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(max) = 'dbo.[TableName]'
   ,@MetaTable NVARCHAR(128) = '#TempTable'
   ,@ColumnName NVARCHAR(128)
   ,@Iterator INT = 1
   ,@SQL1 NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT c.NAME
  ,c.COLUMN_ID
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COLUMN_ID) AS RN
INTO #Cols
FROM SYS.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@Table);

WHILE @Iterator <= (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(RN),0) FROM #Cols)
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = (SELECT NAME FROM #Cols WHERE RN = @Iterator)
     SET @SQL1 =  'INSERT INTO ' + @MetaTable + ' (Table_Name, Column_Name, 
                   Fill_Rate) '
              + 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@Table,'DBO.','') + ''', ''' + 
      @ColumnName + ''', 100 * CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,3), SUM(CASE WHEN [' + 
      @ColumnName + '] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)) / COUNT(1) AS [' + 
      @ColumnName + '_fill]' + ' FROM ' + @Table

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL1
    SET @Iterator += 1
    END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Using system tables directly is not recommended, they might change in teh next SQL Server version. Instead, use *information_schema views*. For the columns, use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and for the tables use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`. he `COLUMN`view also contains an `ORDINAL_POSITION`, so you would not need a `ROW_NUMBER` for them.

Comment: @WolfgangKais the information_schema views are not always accurate and they don't always contain all the information. https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views Curious where you heard that you should not use sys.columns or sys.tables. As for ordinal position of columns, it is in sys.columns (column_id).

Comment: @SeanLange I have tought not to use **system tables** to my students in more then 10 years of being an MCT, as it is stated in the Microsoft official courseware  My bad that I didn't notice that `sys.columns` in the OP is a **catalog view**. You are right, of course, these can be used as well (and scripts will be compatible in future MSSQL versions), but in this question, I don't see any advantage over information schema views (except maybe the length of the name). All the detailed data mentioned in the blog post aren't needed in our case. Thanks anyway for the link, very much appreciated! :-)

Comment: Not sure what you mean then by system tables. Are you referring to tables in master like spt_values? That is the only table I can think of that would be a system table that I have seen used directly. Knowing that inflection is lost on the internet, I am honestly trying to understand here, not at all trying to sound critical.

Comment: @SeanLange, with [system tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/system-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) I mean the secret place where SQL Server stores the metadata on all objects in a database ("database catalog") or even the server-level objects ("system catalog" in the *master* database). These tables are hidden well but can be accessed directly (like the "sysobjects" table instead of the "sys.objects" catalog view) which isn't recommended. I just confused "sys.columns" with a system table name.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a cursor for this neat little task:

```
CREATE TABLE #MetaTable (
  TABLE_SCHEMA sysname,
  TABLE_NAME sysname,
  COLUMN_NAME sysname,
  fill_rate float NULL);

DECLARE 
  @schema sysname,
  @table sysname,
  @column sysname,
  @sql nvarchar(max);

DECLARE column_cusor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
  SELECT s.name, t.name, c.name
    FROM sys.schemas s
      INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id;

OPEN column_cusor;
FETCH NEXT FROM column_cusor INTO @schema, @table, @column;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  SET @sql = 'SELECT ' +  QUOTENAME(@schema, '''') 
    + ', ' + QUOTENAME(@table, '''') 
    + ', ' + QUOTENAME(@column, '''') 
    + ', ' + '100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(@column)
      + ' IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) /'
      + ' CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE COUNT(*) END' 
    + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table);

  INSERT INTO #MetaTable (TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, fill_rate)
  EXEC (@sql);

  FETCH NEXT FROM column_cusor INTO @schema, @table, @column;
END

CLOSE column_cusor;
DEALLOCATE column_cusor;

SELECT * FROM #MetaTable;
```

Comment: As much as I despise cursors it is just about required here...and nested ones at that. UGH!!! One slight adjustment, if the table has no rows this will get a divide by zero error. +1

Comment: Would have to get creative if they are using deprecated datatypes also as things like (n)text are invalid for counting.

Comment: Same with me according to cursors... :) And thanks again, good point, the OP should define how to handle tables with no records. I'd say they are filled 100%, because non of the (non-existent) rows contains a NULL value. ON the other hand... non of the rows contain a value, so all (non-existent) rows are empty...

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, yes, yes.  at least for ntext etc., the OP had used what all the world calls *conditional aggregation*, I think that should also work for ntext, text and image.

Comment: Yes if it was using the case expression with sum (aka conditional aggregation) that would avoid the issue. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Appreciating your comments, I thought of doing it all over, using catalog views, conditional aggregation and handling empty tables (I also had to allow NULL in the `fill_rate` column for that). Then suudenly it hit me... to do the two of us a favour, I reduced the number of cursors by 50%! ;-)

Comment: Thank you for this it works like a charm!! As you said, I was having a hard time nesting one cursor into another only..
Also, for the tables in my database with no records, it returns a null and not 100% filled now- thanks to your edit.

Comment: @SrishtiJain Thanks for the feedback, glad you like it. I had a lot of fun doing this. :-)